# Federated signin with auth0 on react native without universal login page

Tags: react-native, google-signin, auth0

I´m working on a React Native app where I need to provide 3 login options:

- password/email;
- Google;
- Discord;

I'm using auth0 and I was able to get the password/email working with this code:

```js
const auth0 = new Auth0({
  clientId: auth0Config.clientId,
  domain: auth0Config.domain,
});

auth0.auth
  .passwordRealm({
    username,
    password,
    realm: auth0Config.realm,
    scope: auth0Config.scope,
    audience: auth0Config.audience,
  })
```

unfortunately, I can't find an article, or example on how to integrate Google/Discord signin without using the default universal signin popup

I thought about opening the universal signin only when clicking on Google/Discord option and leaving the password login on the custom page.

Is this the best approach?
Can someone help me with some directions on this?

I'm using the `auth0.auth` option.
I'm not using auth0's auth provider because I don't want to use the universal page.